# View lastlog file on windows

Tags: linux, windows

I want to view lastlog file I got from a linux machine.
I couldn't find anything on the net.
Is there any program that will help me do it on windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is an article about the format of a lastlog file [here](http://www.hcidata.info/lastlog.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The lastlog file in Linux is a binary file containing `struct lastlog` records for each uid that has logged in. The file is a sparse file with each lastlog records stored at offsets determined by the uid.

The C-source for the lastlog command is surprisingly straightforward and shouldn't be too hard to compile under Windows. Unfortunately I do not know of any such ready-built binary.

The lastlog man-page actually describes the file format pretty well:

http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/lastlog/

Altough that is a bit outdated. Linux uses the following definitions:

```
#define UT_LINESIZE     32
#define UT_NAMESIZE     32
#define UT_HOSTSIZE     256


/* The structure describing an entry in the database of
   previous logins.  */
struct lastlog
  {
#if __WORDSIZE == 64 && defined __WORDSIZE_COMPAT32
    int32_t ll_time;
#else
    __time_t ll_time;
#endif
    char ll_line[UT_LINESIZE];
    char ll_host[UT_HOSTSIZE];
  };
```